# App Engine Memcache a single value shared across all instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I need to share a single MemCache key in Google App Engine across all the instances. This key is used for reading and incrementing, in a high rate (500 / sec).

Google suggests not to use "hot keys" and they recommend using datastore instead.
Since I cannot increment or decrement a value by a single command in datastore, this is not usable for me.

What other option do I have?

Thanks

Comment: do you understand that memcache is for temp values? it can be lost at any unpredictable moment

Comment: Why temp? Dedicated memcache guarantees durability isn't it?

Comment: @Forepick: dedicated memcache can only protect (with care) against eviction due to memory pressure, but there are other reasons for which memcache values can dissapear, even from dedicated memcache - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/#Python_How_cached_data_expires (and the next section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called Sharding Counters.

Basically you need a few `CounterShard` entities to store value. You break your increment step into independent counters, then load and sum all values when you need it (it's cheap).

For *500/sec* I guess you need up to 100 shards, but I suggest you to make few experiments to find best value.

There're full example hot to use it: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters